# how can i create a sequential reference number in php?

Tags: php, html

can you guys give me an example on how to create a sequential reference number whenever the form is submitted. for example when the user create a account there is a textbox there where the reference number is already output. it will be better if the reference number is starts from 2018-0001. and i want it also to store it into my database.

```
<div class="col col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        Reference: 
                                        <?php       

                                        ?>
                                        <input type="text" name="reference" id="refence" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $reference; ?>"
                                        />
                                        <span class="text-danger">
                                            <?php if (isset($reference_error)) echo $reference_error; ?>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

that is my code for my textbox.

Comment: Please upload the PHP code.

Comment: @user9437856 well i don't have any php code for it, i just want to see an example if available

Comment: @msg well i have a button for it to be save, just want to see the increment reference number in a textbox.

Comment: @msg already post a picture below and a code thanks for helping man!

Comment: @renren, Try this code and get the output 2018-0001, $number = 1;
$year= date("Y");
$userno= str_pad($number, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$number++;
$target=$year."-".$userno;
echo $target;

Comment: @user9437856 thanks man! but can you show me how it will increment whenever the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I already edited my file just want to see 1 number at a time please check the image below.

[my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igmVL.jpg)

here's my code to edit

```
<div class="col col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        Reference: 
                                        <?php       
                                            $number = 1;
                                        ?>
                                        <input type="text" name="reference" id="refence" class="form-control" value="<?php  while ($number <= 10) {
                                            echo str_pad ($number, 12, '2018-000000', STR_PAD_LEFT),' ';
                                            $number++;
                                            } ?>"
                                        />
                                        <span class="text-danger">
                                            <?php if (isset($reference_error)) echo $reference_error; ?>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: I just want to know why you are displaying all the reference number in the reference field in the image. You want to display a single value. right? like 2018-0000001?

Comment: yes. and when the button save click the next time the user will register it will show the incremented value for the reference